# Template errors admin/productbased.tpl

Tags: php, smarty, opencart

I've had to jump on to this project that uses Opencart with no previous OC experience, so please bear with me.

We've had an issue when we log in to admin and click on Extensions > Shipping > Product based shipping.

When we try to add products nothing happens. I've checked the logs and we have the following errors:

Undefined index: status in /home/xxx/public_html/admin/view/template/shipping/productbased.tpl on line 322
Undefined index: name in /home/xxx/public_html/admin/view/template/shipping/productbased.tpl on line 325
Undefined index: model in /home/xxx/public_html/admin/view/template/shipping/productbased.tpl on line 325

Which is the following code:

```
if ($product['status']) {
 $enabled_products[$product_id] = $product['name'] . ' (' .       $product['model'] . ')';
} else {
 $disabled_products[$product_id] = $product['name'] . ' (' . $product['model'] . ')';
}
```

I'm using Opencart Version 1.5.4

Any direction is appreciated.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have assign this product array into `$this->data[]` array in the controller page, after that you can access that product array in to the template section.

like this:

```
$this->data['products'] = $this->model_product_product->getallProduct();
```